# Datasnap mobile connectors

Tags: java, android, datasnap

i'm tryng to connect to datasnap rest server from android;

datasnap server is standard generated code with wizard echo an reversstring. didn't change anything.
it worked in browser from network and on device(not emulator)

srv_ip : 192.168.3.104
dvc_ip : 192.168.3.118

but *.apk seems not working

i have generate the proxy for android and in android studio wrote sample code

```
final Button btncall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncall);

btncall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DSRESTConnection conn = new DSRESTConnection();
        conn.setHost("192.168.3.104");
        conn.setPort(8080);
        TServerMethods1 proxy = new TServerMethods1(conn);

        try {
            textView.setText(proxy.ReverseString(editText.getText().toString()));
        } catch (DBXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        editText.setText("");
    }
});
```

but it's not changing text

**logcat :**

```
    com.embarcadero.javaandroid.DBXException: Connection to http://192.168.3.104:8080 refused
    com.embarcadero.javaandroid.DSRESTConnection.execute(DSRESTConnection.java:347)
    com.embarcadero.javaandroid.DSProxy$TServerMethods1.ReverseString(DSProxy.java:64)
    com.sample.dsclient.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
    android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
    android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17362)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong tnx